# How to speed up a list when there are multiple Group by?

Tags: list-view, grouping

doc library size = 40k

Group by column type is Single line of text

Grouping on multiple columns (some indexed some not)

Sometimes really slow. What are the good practices when I comes to view items for a doc lib or list?

Type of columns good for grouping?
Did Index but not much help?
Should Managed Metadata be implemented for better grouping? (I am not even sure if you can group on managed metadata columns)

Just need some good inside please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much to say about performance implications and measures to improve it, bottom line, yes Indexing indeed help (single or compound) - choose those used in Filtering/Grouping, but also reducing Lookup columns (User, Managed Metadata are lookup columns!!), creating filtered views, and so on.

Please do go through http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx (bottom part explain a lot) and also read  specifics and http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/workingwithlargelist.pdf